# Text enter in one text box gets populated in another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a part of my html code for angularjs app

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" ng-model="myModel.text" 
       name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name."
       data-original-title="Full Name">

<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_email" ng-model="myModel.text"
        name="user_email" rel="popover" data-content="What’s your email address?" 
        data-original-title="Email">
```

Here is my controller code

```
    function MyCtrl2($scope) {
         var initial = {text1: 'initial value'};
         var ini = {text2: 'initialvalue'};
         $scope.myModel = angular.copy(initial);
         $scope.myModel = angular.copy(ini);
}

MyCtrl2.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

What ever I write in first text box automatically gets populated in second text box too.
Why is dat happening.
How to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both of your fields have the same `ng-model`.

To avoid it, use different values for `ng-model` for each input field.

Comment: well i'm new to angular so just a doubt. doesn't myModel.text indicate its a text box or is it only a name

Comment: It does not mean it's a text box

Comment: As long as the `ng-model` is the same for both fields they will both get autopopulated to the same

Answer (score 0):

Because your both input field associate with same model name **myModel.text**